# Autocomplete not working in Visual Studio project in git repository

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, autocomplete

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 (and I'm pretty new to it). When I create new project using the empty c++ project template and select the project directory to be located inside existing git repository code auto completion is not working (also syntax highlighting seems different). When I do the same but the project directory is not located in git repository everything works fine.

I also tried to create the project outside of git repository and then copy it there. Once the code is moved to git repository auto completion stops working.

I already checked that in tools->options->Text Editor , the statement completion is enabled (auto list members, parameter information) for c/c++ as well as all languages.

Comment: I've been using ssh to connect to the remote repository. I created new git repository using http and this one works for me. Anyway this looks like a bug in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove .vs directory from project dir and reopen Visual Studio. After that it seems to work.

Comment: Happens even now with VS 2022, especially after refactoring ‍♂️‍♂️